# Executar código Python chamando por um form do Django

Tags: python, django

boa tarde.

Estou começando a estudar Python e Django. A título de estudo escrevi um código em Python que recebe um valor e uma data e faz a atualização pela TJLP. Isso funcionou perfeitamente.

Como próximo passo eu criei um formulário no Django para que o usuário possa inserir o valor e a data e solicitar a correção acionando um botão. Nesse momento chamo uma view que deverá receber valor/data e retornar o valor atualizado, porém não sei como fazer a view chamar meu código.

Antecipadamente agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/django-view-template1)

Se entendi direito, basta voce checar na view se o seu request usa o metodo POST, se sim, faça o processamento necessário e retorne o resulatado. No exemplo abaixo crio uma template que solicita uma data e um valor, após à submissão do usuário, a view pega o valor, multiplica por 2 e retorna. A view, a partir do primeiro envio do usuário, mostra o que foi digitado no envio anterior e apresenta o valor "corrigido" (multiplicado por 2):

Em views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):

    data = None
    valor = None
    new_valor = None

    if request.method=='POST':
        data = request.POST['data']
        valor = request.POST['valor']
        new_valor = int(valor)*2
        # Faça aqui o que vc for precisos com os dados recebidos

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'data': data, 'valor': valor, 'new_valor': new_valor})
```

Na template (no caso, index.html):

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="data">Data:</label>
    <input id="data" type="date" name="data" value="" /><br>
    <label for="valor">Valor:</label>
    <input id="valor" type="number" name="valor" value="" /><br>
    <input type="submit">

    {% if data != None %}
        <br><br>
        <p>
            Sua última digitação:<br>
            Data Inicial: {{data}}<br>
            Valor: {{valor}}<br>
            Valor Corrigido: {{new_valor}}

        </p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Apresentação da template após o primeiro envio (submit):

[image: Execucao template django repl.it]

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/django-view-template1)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.